# i want to compare the current row and previous row using a "single cursor" and update the rows in sql

Tags: sql, cursor, cursor-position

I have the following table

```
icode    iname   icatcode      slno
10           a      11            0
20           b      31            0
30           c      11            0
40           d      21            0
50           e      31            0
60           f      11            0
70           g      21            0
80           h      41            0
```

I need to update the `slno` column using cursor.

The output should be the following table ie., when the `icatcode` is same it should increment the `slno` & wen `icatcode` changes it should set the `slno` to 1

```
icode    iname   icatcode      slno
10           a             11            1
30           b             11            2
60           c             11            3
70           d             21            1
40           e             21            2
50           f             31            1
20           g             31            2
80           h             41            1
```

I have written the query for it

```
declare @icode int,@iccode int, @islno int,@inccode int
set @islno=1
declare cur2 cursor for select icode,iccode from im
order by iccode
open cur2
fetch next from cur2 into @icode,@iccode
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
    update im  set slno=@islno where @icode=icode
    fetch next from cur2 into @icode,@inccode
    if @iccode<>@inccode
    begin
    set @islno=1
    end
    else
    begin
    set @islno=@islno+
    end
end
close cur2
deallocate cur2
```

The above query results in the following output

```
icode    iname   icatcode      slno
10           a             11            1
20           b             31            1
30           c             11            2
40           d             21            1
50           e             31            1
60           f             11            3
70           g             21            1
80           h             41            1
```

What changes do I need so that I will get the desired output?

**NOTE:** We should solve this only using "CURSORS" in sql 2008

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171578/compare-two-rows-using-a-single-cursor-in-sql/15173062#15173062

Comment: I started a very basic example of counting previous matching rows here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ea19/1 but I'm not sure it fully matches your requirements. But hey :) I think a procedure is required.