# Compare two rows using a single cursor in SQL

Tags: sql, cursor, cursor-position

I have the following table

```
+-------+-------+----------+------+
| icode | iname | icatcode | slno |
+-------+-------+----------+------+
|    10 | a     |       11 |    0 |
|    20 | b     |       31 |    0 |
|    30 | c     |       11 |    0 |
|    40 | d     |       21 |    0 |
|    50 | e     |       31 |    0 |
|    60 | f     |       11 |    0 |
|    70 | g     |       21 |    0 |
|    80 | h     |       41 |    0 |
+-------+-------+----------+------+
```

I need to update the *slno* column using a cursor. The o/p should be the following table ie., when the *icatcode* is same it should increment the *slno* and when *icatcode* changes it should set the *slno* to 1.

```
+-------+-------+----------+------+
| icode | iname | icatcode | slno |
+-------+-------+----------+------+
|    10 | a     |       11 |    1 |
|    30 | b     |       11 |    2 |
|    60 | c     |       11 |    3 |
|    70 | d     |       21 |    1 |
|    40 | e     |       21 |    2 |
|    50 | f     |       31 |    1 |
|    20 | g     |       31 |    2 |
|    80 | h     |       41 |    1 |
+-------+-------+----------+------+
```

I have written the query for it

```
declare @icode int,@iccode int,@islno int,@inccode int

set @islno=1

declare cur2 cursor for select icode,iccode from im order by iccode

open cur2

fetch next from cur2 into @icode,@iccode

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0

begin

    update im  set slno=@islno where @icode=icode
    fetch next from cur2 into @icode,@inccode
    if @iccode<>@inccode
    begin
    set @islno=1
    end
    else
    begin
    set @islno=@islno+
    end

end

close cur2
deallocate cur2
```

The above query results the following o/p

```
+-------+-------+----------+------+
| icode | iname | icatcode | slno |
+-------+-------+----------+------+
|    10 | a     |       11 |    1 |
|    20 | b     |       31 |    1 |
|    30 | c     |       11 |    2 |
|    40 | d     |       21 |    1 |
|    50 | e     |       31 |    1 |
|    60 | f     |       11 |    3 |
|    70 | g     |       21 |    1 |
|    80 | h     |       41 |    1 |
+-------+-------+----------+------+
```

What changes do I need to do so that I will get the desired o/p? I need to do this  only by using cursors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: From the TSQL, I am guessing it's MS SQL Sever, please update your tags (as Marc indicated). Unless it's homework, you may not even need a cursor. SQL have many wonderful things that programmers need not do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLServer you can try this

```
DECLARE @icode int,
        @icatcodeOld int,
        @icatcode int,
        @slno int = 1                   

DECLARE cur2 CURSOR
  FOR
    SELECT icode, icatcode
    FROM im    
    ORDER BY icatcode ASC        
  OPEN cur2
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @icode, @icatcode
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN      
      UPDATE im
      SET slno = @slno                  
      WHERE icode = @icode                 

      SET @icatcodeOld = @icatcode                                                             
      FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @icode, @icatcode      
      SELECT @slno = CASE WHEN @icatcodeOld = @icatcode THEN @slno + 1 ELSE 1 END
    END

  CLOSE cur2
  DEALLOCATE cur2
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/050b7/1)